# Linked list in shared memory, linux kernel

Tags: linux, shared-memory

This was an interview question and I am still confused about it.

Implement 2 APIs -  1.to access the head of a linked list which is present in shared memory

2.to access the element after the head

Kernel in the question is Linux.

I read on a forum that instead of using pointers, an offset should be used (is it still a linked list if pointers aren't used)

I don't really understand this part. Also curious about the address translations that will occur, considering virtual memory is in place.

Apologies for the question being vague, but that's all I could figure out.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can't use a pointer because there's no way to ensure that the shared memory is mapped at the same address in both processes. One process would no have idea what to do with a pointer into the other process' virtual address space.

So instead, you store the offset into the block of shared memory. Both processes know exactly what the 712th byte of the block of shared memory is. To access such an offset, you add the offset to the base address at which the block of shared memory is mapped in this particular process, and that creates a pointer you can use within that particular process.

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, you *can* ensure the memory is mapped at the same address. If you create the memory region via `mmap` with the `MAP_SHARED` flag, you can position it wherever you like - so, if your API has the convention that all users must place it at a certain virtual address, pointers will still work.

Comment: @Borealid That's not all that practical on a 32-bit operating system. But on a 64-bit OS, that works quite well.